# With Rails and Devise, how do I set the cookie properties if I'm using ActiveRecord store?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In `myapp/config/initializers/session_store.rb`, I have the following:

```
Myapp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_myapp_session', :domain => :all
```

The `:key` option sets the name to use for the cookie, and `:domain => :all` says that the cookie can be shared across subdomains.

Now I want to move to using ActiveRecord to store the session. If I do this:

```
Myapp::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store
```

... although the session is stored in the database, there is still, of course, a cookie. But I no longer have control over its name or scope.

How can I use ActiveRecord store for the session and still specify the cookie name and domain?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Figured it out

It's very simple, actually:

```
Myapp::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store, :key => '_myapp_session', :domain => :all
```